# Удалить каждый второй элемент списка

Tags: c++, list

Вечер добрый. Нужно написать функцию удаления каждого второго элемента списка. Кучу всего перепробовал, но постоянно удаляет не то, что нужно, или вовсе выбивает ошибку. Ниже привел кусок кода. Может увидите ошибку... Буду крайне благодарен.

```
struct list {
int data;
list *pNext;
};

void deleteItems(list *pStart, int k) {
list *tmp;
list *curr = pStart; // Текущий элемент списка
while( curr ) // Проходим по списку
{
    if( curr->data % 2 == 0 )  // Если элемент четный
    {
        list *tmp = curr->pNext; // удаляемый элемент
        curr->pNext = tmp->pNext; 

        delete tmp;
    }

    curr = curr->pNext;
}
}
```

Comment: ну так data - это данные, а не номер эл-та списка, заведи переменную в цикле (например int num = 1) и каждую итерацию инкрементируй её (добавляй 1 (num++)), когда переменная чётная, удаляй элемент списка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите что вы делаете:

```
list *tmp = curr->pNext;
```

конструктора структура не имеет, поэтому  `tmp->pNext` ни на что не указывает, и еще вы проверили, что  `curr` не нулевой, но вы не знаете  `curr->pNext` нулевой или нет. И в следующей строчке :

```
curr->pNext = tmp->pNext;
```

вы этот неизвестно какой указателью присваиваете указатель, который ни на что не указывает.
Если вы хотите удалять каждый второй элемент, а не те, у которых `data` четное число, то так:

```
void deleteItems(list* pStart, int k) { 
    list* curr = pStart; 
    while (curr->pNext) 
    {       
        list* tmp = curr->pNext; // удаляемый элемент
        if(tmp->pNext)
           curr->pNext = tmp->pNext;        
        delete tmp;
        curr = curr->pNext;
    }
}
```

Нужно всегда проверять используемый указатель

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, какие правки нужно внести? Пока что не очень хорошо все это понимаю

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручили!